# Flutter, calling FutureBuilder from a raised button's onPressed doesn't call the builder property

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to learn Dart/Flutter and am working on an example where there's a button on the app that says "Get Data", and when I touch it I want to retrieve JSON data from a restful service.

I see the web service being called in fetchPost, but the builder property of the FutureBuilder isn't called.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'ResultsList.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Restul Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                FutureBuilder<ResultsList>(
                  future: fetchPost(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                    print('In Builder');
                  }
                );
              },
              child: Text('Get data'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

Future<ResultsList> fetchPost() async {
    final response =  await http.get('http://mywebserviceurl');

    if (response.statusCode == 200){
      print('Received data');
      return ResultsList.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    }
    else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
}
```

Interestingly though, if I move the FutureBuilder out of the onPressed of the button to the child of Center, I do see the builder property getting called.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'ResultsList.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Restul Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<ResultsList>(
                future: fetchPost(),
                builder: (context, snapshot){
                  print ('In Builder');
                  return Container();
                }
              )
      )
    );
  }
}

Future<ResultsList> fetchPost() async {
    final response =  await http.get('http://mywebserviceurl');

    if (response.statusCode == 200){
      print('Received data');
      return ResultsList.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    }
    else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
}
```

Obviously I'm missing something, but any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. In `onPressed` update the state using `setState(...)` and then when build is called you can use `FutureBuilder` or don't use `FutureBuilder` at all and use `async`/`await` in `onPressed` and call `setState()` when the async execution is completed.

Comment: `FutureBuilder` is a widget, not a function. It has to be in the widget tree

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `onPressed` method in this `RaisedButton` is actually not doing anything. It just creates a new `FutureBuilder` which does nothing but existing^^ It's like you would just call `1+1;`, which just creates a value, but that value is not used to do anything.

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: (){
    FutureBuilder<ResultsList>(
      future: fetchPost(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        print('In Builder');
      }
    );
  },
  child: Text('Get data'),
)
```

You could have `body` be assigned to a `Widget`(which could just be called `body` or whatever you want^^), which you then change in a `setState((){body = FutureBuilder(/*...*/});` call.

Comment: it doesn't work that solution

Answer (score 52):

If you want to get some data from request - you don't need `FutureBuilder`. You can do:

```
RaisedButton(
          onPressed: (){
            fetchPost().then((result) {
                print('In Builder');
            })
          },
          child: Text('Get data'),
        )
```

or

```
RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            var result = await fetchPost()
            print('In Builder');
          },
          child: Text('Get data'),
        )
```

Comment: Thank you... wasted hours. Is there a benefit using FutureBuilder?

Comment: If you getting some data from async request and after that you have to show widget - then you need `FutureBuilder`. E.g., you have to show result of `fetchPost` request in some widget

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky Is there any way to show a progress indicator while waiting for the future?

Comment: @ZohaibTariq you can update state and show indicator, and hide it after receiving data. But it'd be better to do with StreamBuilder. Or FutureBuilder

Comment: better solution, but I used forget it many times, that anything is replacement of futurebuilder, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For me FutureBuilder not working in onPresses...
I used this way :

I defined a variable in state:

```
    bool visiblity = false;
```

and I used this code in build:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              visiblity=true;
              fetchPost();
            },
            child: Text('Get data'),
          ),
          FutureBuilder<ResultsList>(
              future: ("Your View Model that return from call back"),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (visiblity) {
                  print('In Builder');
                  visiblity=false;
                } else
                  return Container();
              }
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
   );
  }
```

I didn't put FutureBuilder in onPressed. I put that in body and changed visibility after return result.